# GitHub: The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: github, push

For the following git base: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer, 
Previously it is fine.

But for now I can NOT push successfully.

I find a strange thing as fig 1. It is after clone, the remote origin branch is point to "remotes/origin/HEVC".

It seems to that "remotes/origin/HEVC" does NOT exist??

So I got

"fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403"

How can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> It is after clone, the remote origin branch is point to "`remotes/origin/HEVC`".

Fig. 1 does not show that. Maybe it would with `git branch -avv` instead of just `git branch -a`.

The remote default branch is `release-v2`, which should be the branch cloned by default.

As for pushing, unless you are [declared as a collaborator](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/) on that repository, it is perfectly normal to get a 403. You should [fork that repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) in order for you to be able to push back to GitHub.